# Policy on asking for book recommendations

Tags: discussion, support

I want to ask a question asking for book recommendations (specifically an introductory text on cosmology for advanced undergrad/beginning grad level).  I am wondering what the policy is for asking for book recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

Just be careful with recommendation questions that your requirements are pretty narrow. For example:

> What is the best cosmology textbook?

The above is too broad and subjective. The following is better:

> What introductory texts on cosmology for advanced undergrad or beginning grad level would satisfy X, Y, Z needs of mine?

Or something like this:

> What introductory texts on cosmology for advanced undergrad or beginning grad level would contain X, Y, Z information I'm looking for?